# LDAP server (OpenLDAP 2.4.23) search queries hang / never stop

Tags: proxy, active-directory, freeze, openldap

I've been looking for answer for almost two weeks, but didn't find the solution.
I have a OpenLDAP slapd service on my amazon EC2 linux machine inside a VPC network. Im using it as a proxy to our Active Directory. I'm not sure if the configuration is ok - I'm not a network/ldap guru.

Every time I run a ldapsearch against my proxy, the ldapsearch returns results, but **without** the end summary, like:

> search result
>   search: 2
>   result: 0 Success
>   numResponses: 2
>   numEntries: 1

only the last attribute is written to the output... and it hangs endlessly, so I'm not able to put new command to the prompt. The log keeps growing with the following entries:

> Nov 14 15:53:55 ip-10-0-0-121 slapd[21936]: daemon: epoll: listen=7 active_threads=1 tvp=zero
>   Nov 14 15:53:55 ip-10-0-0-121 slapd[21936]: daemon: epoll: listen=8 active_threads=1 tvp=zero
>   Nov 14 15:53:55 ip-10-0-0-121 slapd[21936]: daemon: epoll: listen=9 active_threads=1 tvp=zero
>   Nov 14 15:53:56 ip-10-0-0-121 slapd[21936]: daemon: epoll: listen=7 active_threads=1 tvp=zero
>   Nov 14 15:53:56 ip-10-0-0-121 slapd[21936]: daemon: epoll: listen=8 active_threads=1 tvp=zero
>   Nov 14 15:53:56 ip-10-0-0-121 slapd[21936]: daemon: epoll: listen=9 active_threads=1 tvp=zero
>   Nov 14 15:53:57 ip-10-0-0-121 slapd[21936]: daemon: epoll: listen=7 active_threads=1 tvp=zero
>   Nov 14 15:53:57 ip-10-0-0-121 slapd[21936]: daemon: epoll: listen=8 active_threads=1 tvp=zero
>   Nov 14 15:53:57 ip-10-0-0-121 slapd[21936]: daemon: epoll: listen=9 active_threads=1 tvp=zero
>   Nov 14 15:53:58 ip-10-0-0-121 slapd[21936]: daemon: epoll: listen=7 active_threads=1 tvp=zero
>   Nov 14 15:53:58 ip-10-0-0-121 slapd[21936]: daemon: epoll: listen=8 active_threads=1 tvp=zero
>   Nov 14 15:53:58 ip-10-0-0-121 slapd[21936]: daemon: epoll: listen=9 active_threads=1 tvp=zero

My slapd.d config files are:

**cn=config.ldif**

> dn: cn=config
>   objectClass: olcGlobal
>   cn: config
>   olcConfigFile: /etc/openldap/slapd.conf.bak
>   olcConfigDir: /etc/openldap/slapd.d
>   olcAllows: bind_v2
>   olcArgsFile: /var/run/openldap/slapd.args
>   olcAttributeOptions: lang-
>   olcAuthzPolicy: none
>   olcConcurrency: 0
>   olcConnMaxPending: 100
>   olcConnMaxPendingAuth: 1000
>   olcGentleHUP: FALSE
>   olcIdleTimeout: 5
>   olcLogLevel: -1
>   olcIndexSubstrIfMaxLen: 4
>   olcIndexSubstrIfMinLen: 2
>   olcIndexSubstrAnyLen: 4
>   olcIndexSubstrAnyStep: 2
>   olcIndexIntLen: 4
>   olcLocalSSF: 71
>   olcPidFile: /var/run/openldap/slapd.pid
>   olcReadOnly: FALSE
>   olcReverseLookup: FALSE
>   olcSaslSecProps: noplain,noanonymous
>   olcSockbufMaxIncoming: 262143
>   olcSockbufMaxIncomingAuth: 16777215
>   olcThreads: 16
>   olcTLSCACertificatePath: /etc/openldap/certs
>   olcTLSCertificateFile: "OpenLDAP Server"
>   olcTLSCertificateKeyFile: /etc/openldap/certs/password
>   olcTLSVerifyClient: never
>   olcToolThreads: 1
>   olcWriteTimeout: 0

**olcDatabase={0}config.ldif**

> dn: olcDatabase={0}config
>   objectClass: olcDatabaseConfig
>   olcDatabase: {0}config
>   olcAccess: {0}to *  by dn.base="gidNumber=0+uidNumber=0,cn=peercred,cn=external,cn=auth" manage  by * none
>   olcAddContentAcl: TRUE
>   olcLastMod: TRUE
>   olcMaxDerefDepth: 15
>   olcReadOnly: FALSE
>   olcRootDN: cn=config
>   olcSyncUseSubentry: FALSE
>   olcMonitoring: FALSE
>   structuralObjectClass: olcDatabaseConfig

**olcDatabase={1}ldap.ldif**

> dn: olcDatabase={1}ldap
>   objectClass: olcDatabaseConfig
>   objectClass: olcLDAPConfig
>   olcModuleload: back_ldap.la
>   olcDatabase: {1}ldap
>   olcSuffix: dc=domain,dc=com
>   olcAccess: {0}to * by * read
>   olcAccess: {1}to * by * read
>   olcReadOnly: TRUE
>   olcRootDN: uid=admin,dc=domain,dc=com
>   olcRootPW: secret
>   olcSizeLimit: 500
>   olcDbURI: ldap://10.192.0.10
>   olcDbRebindAsUser: TRUE
>   olcIdleTimeout: 5
>   olcDbACLBind: bindmethod=simple timeout=5 network-timeout=5 binddn="CN=user,OU=Users,DC=domain,DC=com" credentials="secret"

and the default **olcDatabase={-1}frontend.ldif** is created.

I have found an answer which is relevant to database indexes problem, but since I don't use a database in my proxy it's not the issue. Querying AD directly by ldapsearch does not hang either.

Any ideas why does it hang?